# How to use repository with web api2

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, repository, unity-container

work on asp.net mvc web api2. My project repository container is Unity.When i call a controller action base on url show me bellow error "**An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'UserInfoController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.**"

In my controller if i put parameter less constructor then how to DI by my repo container unity.

Controller:

```
 public class UserInfoController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWorkAsync _unitOfWorkAsync;
        private readonly IUserInfoService _userInfoService;


        public UserInfoController(IUnitOfWorkAsync unitOfWorkAsync, IUserInfoService userInfoService)
        {
            this._unitOfWorkAsync = unitOfWorkAsync;
            this._userInfoService = userInfoService;

        }


        [Route("api/Userinfos")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<UserInfo, UserInfoEntity>();
            var userInfos = _userInfoService.GetsUserInfos();
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserInfo>, IEnumerable<UserInfoEntity>>(userInfos));
            return response;
        }

        [Route("api/IsValidUser/{userName}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string userName)
        {
            var userInfos = _userInfoService.UserValidatyCheckByUserName(userName);
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, userInfos);
            return response;
        }

    }
```

write http://localhost:23023/api/Userinfos on browser show me the error controller must have parameterless constructor.

What to do?How to use repository with web api.

Comment: You need to add the dependency resolver, see: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

Comment: Mark PM,thanks for your reply.will you please tell me how dependency -resolver solve my problem?

Comment: It will construct your controller with the parameter constructor passing in the relevant repository.

Comment: Mark PM,thanks for your valuable information,it's i am looking.One more thing after add unity repo container from nuget package I get file named UnityConfig.cs on my App_Start folder, it contains several methods like: GetConfiguredContainer, RegisterTypes.will you please tell me where to put this resolver.

Comment: Have a look at the "Dependency Resolution with the Unity Container" section in the article.

Comment: Mark PM thanks for your reply,yah your referred article help a lot they configure repository content on webapiConfig but i want to implement this on UnityConfig.cs file.WIll you please show me some syntax how to use resolver on unityConfig.cs file's method.Thank

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like...